# Suggestion how to make a grid in banner

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

On this page:(I just set a red and green border to make it more clear)

I have a picture of a book, which need to be in the left side where the black border is:

I have tried to build up the banner with the code below. But I cannot figure out how I can set a div tag that would fit the left side where the black border is.

Does anybody have an advice on how I could do that?. The code there is until now is this:

```
<div class="top-area" style="border: 4px solid red;">
    <div class="container" style="border: 4px solid green;">

        @if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(headerText))
        {
            if (pageAlias == "Blog")
            {
                <h1 class="header-xl center">
                    @Html.Raw(headerText)
                </h1>
            }
            else
            {
                <p class="header-xl center">
                    @Html.Raw(headerText)
                </p>
            }
        }
        @if (CurrentPage.HasValue("imageTeaserText"))
        {
            <p class="sub-header center">
                @Html.Raw(CurrentPage.imageTeaserText)
            </p>
        }


    </div>
</div>

<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12 main-content" id="main-content">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-12">
                            @CurrentPage.GetGridHtml("inovoGrid")
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "my div tags are jumping around". Is the picture of the book supposed to be ON the large image?

Comment: Maybe it was a bit unclear what I wanted, I apologize. I just have a deadline tomorrow, and nothing has been working for me today. I tried ti update my question, I hope it is more clear now what I mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here's an example on plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/cWGf9i81nbD4IxOiw40D?p=preview) using the bootstrap columns to keep elements aligned on either side of your title. Bootstrap aligns its grid based on 12 columns. I've only added support for small density screens via `col-sm-x`, you should experiment with the other densities.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will play around with that. How would you get the yellow left content under the text on small devices here? https://plnkr.co/edit/BBZGhsy0kAaK2k0Bmxa9 Can I pull-right somehow?